# How can I upload all photos from a burst on the iPhone?

Tags: dropbox, iphone

I use Dropbox's automatic upload on the iPhone. Whenever I take a photo, it gets uploaded.

But when I take a burst of photos on the iPhone 5s, only one of them is uploaded. I have to go in and tap Select Favorites and mark each one. How can I change it to mark all photos in the burst as Favorites, or get Dropbox to upload all of them?

I find a computer with a big screen much better suited to the task of comparing photos and picking one.

Comment: Doesn't Apple's PhotoStream function work to reliably upload all burst photos to a computer?

Comment: Thanks, but I don't use iCloud services when I can avoid the, due to the Apple lock-in. Doesn't iOS let apps access all the photos in a burst? Or does it let them know only of the favorite photos?

Comment: Settings > Photos and Videos > Turn upload burst photos. Imports through iPhoto on Mac. Dunno about PC. I'll update my PC iTunes and see. Then add to Dropbox from there. Extra step, but whatcha gonna do? I'll see if I can figure out a more direct way soon.

Comment: Thanks, but syncing with a Mac is not the solution I asked for, nor do I have iPhoto on my Mac.

Comment: See if Google Plus can back up a burst photo. If it can, then tell Dropbox about their missing feature that G+ has.

Comment: @geoO it doesn't seem that it can.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For now, the only way to upload all burst photos to Dropbox natively is to connect your iPhone to a computer with a cable, and let Dropbox Camera Upload sync. There it uploads all the photos, and not just the single image as it does while syncing wirelessly.

I too have struggled with a solution to this problem, and pray that in the future it will be resolved...

Comment: Does this still work?