# Export all images in a burst photo in Photos to separate images on my laptop

Tags: macos, photos

I've looked at all the items listed at the end, and still can not find any instructions that match what I see on my laptop in terms of exporting to files on my hard drive.

**Question:** I have a burst with 18 photos that were transferred to the Photos.app on my MacBook with macOS 10.15.7 from my iPhone 6. I want to export all of them to 18 separate images on my hard drive. Is this possible without going to "the cloud" first or installing more software?

[image: can't export all images from a burst photo in Photos.app in macOS]

**above:** I've selected all 18 images by going through them using the right-left arrows to scroll through the row at the bottom and clicking each image so that a check mark appeared in the bottom right of every image. Then I clicked the blue `Done` at the top right of the display. I never saw a "keep all" button mentioned in some Apple tutorials but perhaps those were for previous versions.

**below::** The appearance is unchanged in the main photos window, and I only have options to export 1 photo. If I go back to the burst selector feature (in the first screen shot) and select a few items, click done, then come back here, I still don't have the option to export anything other than one photo.

No matter what I do I can't get (for example) the "export GIF" feature to work either. (note: I want the individual photos, the GIF feature being blank indicates that I'm still missing some step).

[image: can't export all images from a burst photo in Photos.app in macOS]

Apple proper:

- https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7384988
- https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8280265
- https://discussions.apple.com/thread/251253168
- https://help.apple.com/photos/mac/1.0/?lang=en#/pht56eafa987

Apple SE:

- [How Do I Import Burst Photos That Aren't Being Recognized By My iMac?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/245358)
- [How can I upload all photos from a burst on the iPhone?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/118871)
- [Apple Photos: can I force it to treat 'burst' photos as separate items?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/357266)
- [How can I select a single photo from a photo burst using Photos.app on macOS Catalina?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/401127)

Comment: When I import a burst from my iPhone to my MacBook (running 10.15.7) using Photos.app after connecting my phone to my laptop, it showed up as 8 separate images that I could select to import in the macOS Photos app. However, when I went to an existing burst in the mac Photos app, after following the steps of selecting all photos in the burst and hitting done, I was presented with a dialogue box that said "Would you like to keep the other 13 photos in this burst?", and hitting "Keep everything" added all photos in the burst to the Photos library, where I can select them and export all.

Comment: @beninato Thanks, I'll give it a try once again. What you describe certainly sounds like what I'd like and expect to happen, and because it didn't happen for me is why I posted my question. I'll check in a few minutes and update here...